# Xcode Deploy to iPhone 5 and later?

Tags: ios

My app does not play nice with 3.5 inch screens. How do I deploy to the iPhone 5 and later only? So far my solution is to make the valid architecture arm64 only. But this leaves out the iPhone 5 & 5C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not building for iphone 4s goes against Apples choice of allowing it to go to iOS9, which is probably why they don't allow people to choose specific device support in the Info.plist.  You can only filter out by features,  so perhaps look for a feature that is not in iPhone 4s but in other devices, and say you only support that type.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html